# Verify account status

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if account status is verified. This is done through a ENUM column in Mysql table. I've be able to change status to verified"yes" but cant seem to check if it is yes or no. I've tried different ways of the below code but to no avail. Thanks guys in advance.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include '/home/wc002/include/dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $username  = strip_tags(trim($_POST['myusername']));
    $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['mypassword']));
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);

    // Register $myusername, $mypassword
    $_SESSION["myusername"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["mypassword"] = $password;

    //Check if account is Verified
    //$query ="SELECT Verified FROM Member WHERE Verified = false;";
    //$check = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    //if ($check == true){
    //  echo "Please Verfiy your account";
    //}
    //else{

    //Check username matches
    $query1="SELECT `Password`, `salt` FROM `Member` WHERE `Username`='$username'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to TwitchMain.php   again.
    {
        die(header("location:TwitchMain.php?loginFailed=true&reason=blank"));
    }

    $userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));

    //Incorrect password. So, redirect to TwitcMain.php again.
    if($hash != $userData['Password']) 
    {
        die(header("location:TwitchMain.php?loginFailed=true&reason=password"));
    } else { 
   // Redirect to home page after successful login.
        header('Location: Twitch.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What if you adopt the commented out code to just the way you read rows from the database like you do for the Member table? `$check` is a mysqli ressource identifier from where you might retrieve a result set with `mysqli_fetch_array(...` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to your readout, if your column name is 'ENUM', check after the success if ($userData['ENUM'] == 1).

```
   if($hash != $userData['Password']) 
    {
        die(header("location:TwitchMain.php?loginFailed=true&reason=password"));
    } else { 
   // Redirect to home page after successful login.
        if ($userData['Verified'] == 'YES'){
            header('Location: Twitch.php');
        } else {
            die('account not activated');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for input ..Column is name is Verified the type is ENUM

Comment: Thanks Fyntasia changed the ENUM to Verifed and == 1 to 'YES'.. Works thanks mate :)

Comment: Edited for clarity, glad to be of assistance!